# How can I create a windows service that listens to a directory and then sftp's it to a local directory

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, msmq

I'm looking for a starting point and I know my solution has to incorporate MSMQ as part of it.

I have a server that users drop a file into a directory. I have a client that listens to the directory and when something is dropped into that directory the client SFTP's it to a local directory.

Can some one give me a starting point of what technologies I may need to implement this?

A previous developer used Top Shelf and Mass Transit but we have been asked to create our own version as we won't need all the functionality that is available in these two projects. That and also those two open source projects haven't been to reliable.

Thanks.

Comment: I wrote an application that does something similar to this for my company I'd be happy to answer any specific questions that you have, but the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher is a good starting point. I woudl advise you to read-up on it first though, because there are caveats with its use and you will want to make sure that it fulfills your needs.

Comment: What has MSMQ got to do with file watching?  Are you mixing the two technologies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think looking at  `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` will be good starting point if you are planning to implement in .net